# Detect "www" portion of URL, regardless of included "http://"

Tags: php, parsing, url

I have a site on a staging and production server. Staging address is "www-staging.example.com" while production is just "www.example.com".

Using PHP, I need to be able to detect the "www" portion, and check if it's "www-staging" or not. This also must work regardless of if the URL includes the protocol bit "http://".

```
input: "www-staging.example.com" || "http://www-staging.example.com" || "https://www-staging.example.com" || www-staging.example.com/a/directory"

Expected Output: true.


input: "www.example.com" || "http://www.example.com" || "https://www.example.com" || example.com/a/directory

Expected Output: false.
```

My initial approach was to use `parse_url()`, however that does not parse the 'www-' component.

Comment: Can you use javascript instead? And then you can just send the value to your php script

Comment: No I can't, unfortunately. This is occurring before JS has been sent to the page.

Comment: If the http:// part is missing add it then use `parse_url`

Comment: tell me some more context behind this. there might be a different way.. is this script receiving a response from your 2 servers? why does it need to identify?

Comment: @RobMullins it's for a WordPress site. I want to ensure that when the client ports from staging server to production server, the site name / url ( what you set inside the WordPress admin panel) are automatically changed to the appropriate server. Currently we have to change it manually every time we port from stage to prod.

Comment: Okay, how do you port it over? Are you simply migrating the database?

Comment: The site name/url is stored right in the db i believe row 1 of wp_options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a job for... Regular expression (?:wo)?man!

Well, under certain conditions. Namely:

- Your domain is always `example.com` -- this won't work if you need it across multiple sites, though that functionality isn't hard to implement.

Anyway, this should do it:

```
preg_match('^(?:https?:\/\/)?www(?:-staging)?\.example\.com\/', $url)
```

Of course, replace `example\.com` with your actual domain name, with `.` escaped as `\.`.

If you don't want to put that regex in another, and don't plan on getting the specific match, you can simplify it a bit:

```
preg_match('^(https?:\/\/)?www(-staging)?\.example\.com\/', $url)
```

It ought to work the same, though I'm too tired and not experienced with PHP enough to say for sure.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xG4uI8/1).